# Problem after global migration from MS Flow to Power Automate

Tags: migration, flow, power-automate

After Migration from Microsoft Flow to Power Automate, The "**Use data from Office 365 Outlook**" option in **Flow Test** has been removed.

It was on Test Flow button. After migration it's disappeared.

Can anyone please tell me how can I plug it in Power Automate structure?

[image]

If I now start a Flow I have got only Two option. I no have got a Gmail option too:[image]

If I connect this two controls I have got only two options:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed this too. I was showing the **Use data from Office 365 Outlook** option while using **When a new email arrives (V2)** trigger in Microsoft flow.

But I am no longer able to find this trigger in Microsoft flow. I guess they have replaced it with **When a new email arrives (V3)** trigger (Outlook Version 3 trigger) and it is not supporting the **Use data from Office 365 Outlook** option in Flow Test.

However, when I am trying to use **When a new email arrives** trigger for **Gmail**, I can see the 3rd option **Use data from Gmail** as follows:

[image]

**Related Reference**:

[Test your flow by using example data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/business-applications-release-notes/april18/microsoft-flow/test-flow-using-sample-data).

Comment: And I have got only two options

Comment: How could I Change a triger without change all solutions

Comment: I added a screen and i have got only two option in a new flow. could You tell me how add gmail. Meybe that's solution to add Outlook mail ?

Comment: Gmail option will come only when you have added "When a new email arrives (Gmail)" trigger in your flow. check the trigger in image attached in my answer.

Comment: Still I have got only two options

Comment: I connected please look and I have got only two options.